# opencart - Authorize.net confirm button "please wait" no redirection

Tags: php, json, opencart, payment-gateway, authorize.net

We are using opencart-1.5.6 and installed authorize.net(AIM) and PayPal as the payment gateway.But while we checkout using authorize.net, the card is processed and cash is deducted from credit card successfully, but the page is not redirecting to the confirmation page.Mail is sent successfully to admin and also purchase status is also set as completed.But the page still stuck in showing a please wait message.
System is working in the sandbox mode and issue happens when its live.
I would greatly appreciate if you can help.

Comment: Does the error logs say something?

Comment: We are getting certain errors like,
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: entry_company in /home/content/80/6587480/html/mysite/libs/opencart/catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/payment_address.tpl on line 43

But the variable like 'entry_company' are commented fields and not passed to checkout.

Comment: Ok. Please fix that error. Are you getting any error in browser error console after calling the ajax function? I just researched and found this link: http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=99280 - may help you.

Comment: @SankarV There is no error in browser error console.We too had gone through forum link.
About the error notice,those variable are not used for checkout purpose.

Comment: I still have the feeling that you can find the issue from the ajax response. Please check the ajax response using firebug (Firefox plugin) or any such tool.

Comment: As **SankarV** is recommending, exploring the response for the *confirm* AJAX request is the best bet - there might be no direct error in console, but since AJAX response contains invalid JSON due to possible PHP errors being printed out, the redirect to a success page could not be performed. So again, **explore the AJAX response for the *confirm* request and come back with anything suspicious within it**. And though some `entry_company` might not take place in the checkout, since it is echoed somewhere while not instantiated, the PHP Notice is raised thus making the JSON response invalid...

Comment: @shadyyx Thanx a lot .//AJAX response contains invalid JSON due to possible PHP errors being printed out// This helped us to fix the issue.

Comment: @SankarV Your reply too helped us a lot.The fields not used where commented in out tpl page.

Comment: OK, I'll add the comment as answer so that You can accept it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **SankarV** is recommending, exploring the response for the *confirm* AJAX request is the best bet - there might be no direct error in console, but since AJAX response contains invalid JSON due to possible PHP errors being printed out, the redirect to a success page could not be performed. So again, **explore the AJAX response for the confirm request and come back with anything suspicious within it**.

And though some `entry_company` might not take place in the checkout, since it is echoed somewhere while not instantiated, the *PHP Notice* is raised thus making the JSON response invalid...